# How to remove header in latex?

Tags: header, latex

I only want to keep the page number at the bottom and nothing header.But using the following commands I am still getting chapter name and section in the header

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}
\cfoot{\vspace*{1.5\baselineskip}\thepage}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

`\pagestyle{plain}` should take care of that. For single pages `\thispagestyle{plain}`
http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/layout/fancyhdr.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The fancyhdr doc explains the problem.

> Some LATEX commands, like \chapter, use the \thispagestyle command to automatically switch
>   to the plain page style, thus ignoring the page style currently in effect. To customize even such
>   pages you must redefine the plain pagestyle.

And it suggests

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[C]{\bfseries \thepage} % except the center
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
```